# Selenium chromedriver is not starting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:18562 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'MAC-SANU', ip: '192.168.0.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

My script:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("test-type"); capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\SeleniumWork‌​space\\NVState\\chro‌​medriver.exe"); 
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Please add the Script that you used.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
  
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("test-type");
     capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\SeleniumWorkspace\\NVState\\chromedriver.exe");
     capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

     driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Do you get any error message? It would be helpful to post it

Comment: I just helped a colleague debug a similar issue where chromedriver was not starting. In his case, it seems like it was the environment variable HTTP_PROXY that was at fault. When we removed the environment variable the driver was able to start normally.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of changes your need to incorporate stepwise as follows:

1. Provide absolute path of the chromedriver:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe");`

2. Take help of ChromeOptions Class:

`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();`

3. Add the options:

`options.addArguments("test-type");`

4. Take help of DesiredCapabilities Class:

`DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();`

5. Add the options within capabilities:

`capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);`

6. Initialize instance of WebDriver with ChromeDriver along with capabilities:

`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);`

7. Open a URL:

`driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");`

Let me know if this helps you.